# how to avoid sorting while parsing json data in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, json

I am parsing the json data in iphone sdk, but the problem is after i parsed it i am getting the data in sorted order based on the alphabetic.
when i see the json structure in json online viwer i am getting the objects correctly something like
Physician name:
Designation:
Adress:
Fax:

but after i parsed the json data in iphone i am getting some thing like this

Adress:
Designation:
Fax:
PhysicianName:

how to avoid the sorting while parsing the json in iphone.

Comment: What are you using to parse the JSON? SBJSON?

Comment: Could you add a JSON source code example ?

Comment: I dont think you need to consider the order of the keys while parsing JSON data? Do you make conclusions based on the order of the JSON content?

Comment: @iceydee: Yes i am using SBJSON.

Comment: @Krishnan: Yes the order server sending need to be displayed but after parsing json the order is changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you use a `NSDictionary` to parse the data into. And i guess `NSDictionary` sorts them based on keys. why do you want to worry about order if you are going to access it based on keys.

**UPDATE**

```
allValues
```

> Returns a new array containing the
>   dictionary’s values.
>
> ```
> - (NSArray *)allValues
> ```
>
> Return Value
>
> A new array containing the
>   dictionary’s values, or an empty array
>   if the dictionary has no entries.
>
> **Discussion**
>
> The order of the values in the array
>   isn’t defined.

It clearly states the order is not defined. So i guess its better to use the dictionary as such and use the keys to load your table

Comment: Hi, Thank for quick response.i want the same order bcz i am getting the key and value pairs both from server, i don't know the order, so what ever order i am getting from the server i am retriving the info from dictionary after parsing as [dict allvalues] and [dict allkeys] and i am using this data to load it into table, in the table this order shouldn't be missed.

Comment: It is better to get the dict as such and use the keys to fill your table.

Comment: Hi, I did the same took the allvalues from the dictionary and formed the order.thanks

Answer (score 3):

Order in Json object is unspecified and is application dependent.
If your values are ordered you have to put them in a list.

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt

The RFC only specify that key should be unique.

Your question is a duplicate from :
[JSON order mixed up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948206/json-order-mixed-up)

- Why do you need to keep the order ?
- Do you have any control of the data coming from the server ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply VGE. what i want is after i parsed the json i am getting the sorted objects based on alphabetic. i need as it is object structure. don't want sorted objects. for iphone i found some json library, when i parsed the data the output i am getting in sorted format.