# simple-json is shuffling my data

Tags: java, jquery, json

i'm using [json-simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) to write json.
and on my sql query i use order by epoch desc. but simple-json is rearranging everything and i cant read in the right sequence in my jquery.
how do i stop this?

```
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        while (rs.next()) {
            Long epoch = rs.getLong(4);
            String data = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(new java.util.Date(epoch * 1000));
            String hora = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(new java.util.Date(epoch * 1000));
            JSONObject sub = new JSONObject();
            sub.put("id", rs.getInt(1));
            sub.put("idUser", rs.getInt(2));
            if ("".equals(name)) {
                sub.put("user", user.getNameById(rs.getInt(2)));
            } else {
                sub.put("user", name);
            }
            sub.put("recado", rs.getString(3));
            sub.put("epoch", rs.getLong(4));
            sub.put("data", data);
            sub.put("hora", hora);
            obj.put(rs.getInt(1), sub);
        }
        return obj.toJSONString();
```

thanks

Comment: JSONs are unordered: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4920304/1850609. Here's  something that may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6993892/1850609

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON is an unordered data format, you need to sort again after receiving the data.