# preserving order while selecting from DB using hibernate and spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, json

guys i have 2 tables "employee" which has EMPID, EMPAGE, ADDRESS, SALARY, EMPNAME, department_id (foreign key refrences to table "department") and "department" table which has department_id, name ... i made a HQL query to select the departments

```
public List<Department> listDepartment() {
    List<Department> deps = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                           .createCriteria(Department.class).list();
    return deps;
}
```

and i looped through the table to construct JSON object to be called by ajax request

```java
    public void listDepartment(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, JSONException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

        for(int index = 0; index<listDepartment().size(); index++){
            obj1.put("Department ID "+index,listDepartment().get(index).getDepId());
            obj1.put("Department Name "+index,listDepartment().get(index).getDepName());

            JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
            for(Employee l : listDepartment().get(index).getEmployees()){
                array.add(l.getEmpId()+" "+l.getEmpAge()+" "+l.getSalary()+" "+l.getEmpAddress());
                obj1.put("Employees "+index, array);
            }

        }

        System.out.println(obj1);
        obj.put("MyListDep", obj1);
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        out.write(obj.toString());
        out.close();
```

but i found the 'obj1' to be like this

> {"Department Name 0":"name1","Department Name 1":"name2","Department
>   Name 2":"name3","Department Name 3":"name4","Department Name
>   4":"name5","Employees 0":["1 10 salary1 address1","2 20 salary2
>   address2"],"Department ID 0":1,"Department ID 1":2,"Employees 2":["5
>   50 salary5 address5","6 60 salary6 address6"],"Employees 1":["3 30
>   salary3 address3","4 40 salary4 address4"],"Department ID
>   2":3,"Department ID 3":4,"Department ID 4":5,"Employees 4":["9 90
>   salary9 address9","10 100 salary10 address10"],"Employees 3":["7 70
>   salary7 address7","8 80 salary8 address8"]}

not preserving the order .. so i want it to print all information of index 0 then index 1 then ... etc 
any help ??

Comment: You are returning a json object. Object keys do not have a set order. You need to change the result to an array.

Comment: As JSON objects do not inherently have an order, you should use an array within your JSON object to ensure order.

Comment: Here is more information about the issue and how or resolve it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993645/ordered-jsonobject

Comment: Are you taking about column order or row order or both