# How do I download the Gson library?

Tags: github, jar, zip, gson

Should be simple question.

When I go to https://github.com/google/gson I can only download the library as a zip folder as opposed to a jar file.

Where can I get the jar file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First you need to clone the repository locally on your computer:

```
git clone https://github.com/google/gson
```

Then you go inside the project folder ./gson and you create the jar file running:

```
mvn package
```

Of course to do this you need to have maven installed, if you are under osx you can install it running

```
brew install maven
```

Otherwise you can look for the installation for your system on the [maven official website](https://maven.apache.org/install.html)

After running mvn package the jar file will be in ./gson/gson/target/gson-2.7.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Comment: I am running Elementary OS by the way. Got this error after running 'mvn package' http://pastebin.com/tXFS24nH

Comment: try to install it with

    sudo apt-get purge maven maven2 maven3
    sudo apt-add-repository ppa:andrei-pozolotin/maven3
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install maven3

as explained [here](http://robferguson.org/2016/03/29/how-to-install-git-maven-and-eclipse-on-elementary-os/)

Comment: Thank you for sorting that for me! One final question; I'm now getting this error http://pastebin.com/EHTK5p9Z How can I run my program? The command line seems to think my .java file is in the package

Comment: Amazing the amount of work needed to do to download a simple jar file. Is there a link to the jar file?

Comment: yes, the readme of the repository points here http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.0/

Comment: Here: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.10.1/ replace the version name with the desired version.

Answer (score 9):

There is a MVN Repo  http://mvnrepository.com/ there you will find how to add to a maven OR in your case how to download the lib jars

[image]

Comment: fyi, "Download from central (JAR)" link is no longer there. Instead, click "central" under Repository row

Comment: This is better. Search gson and download the jar. No clonin..., packin... and brewin...

Answer (score 3):

am bit late but for anyone in future, 
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.0

ofcourse if its vresion changes you can figure it out from the base url.

Answer (score 2):

I just downloaded it here:

https://jar-download.com/explore-java-source-code.php?a=gson&g=com.google.code.gson&v=2.7&downloadable=1

Is working for me.

Comment: It's usually more advisable, namely because of security, to download libraries from official sources: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.2/