# Android JSONObject and Microsoft generic deserialization

Tags: android, wcf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JSON order mixed up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948206/json-order-mixed-up)

By Microsoft convension i need send Json as String where __type going first.

But in Android when i try send json object as StringEntity and then JSONObject calls toString method it's mix fields and __type goes second.

On net deserialization site it's crashes becuase it's cant deserialize object.

How solve its?

Comment: It's not. I not need use thirdpart libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fields in a JSON object are inherently unordered; see [JSON order mixed up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948206/json-order-mixed-up).

If you need a specific ordering, you will have to manually build the JSON data.