# JSONObject keys order reverse

Tags: java, json, org.json

I searched across many sources but could not find the answer to this one..

Its a know fact that a JSONObject keys are returned in reverse order.

Is there any way to recurse through a JSONObject in the correct order as appearing in JSON

```
String json;
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json)
Iterator<String> keys = json.keys()   ---> order is reversed
```

I understand JSONObject is unordered, perhaps there is a way to order it????

JSON is of type below..and the keys start getting recursed from the bottom most styleHint tag

```
"sections": {


 "1": {
    "1": {
      "1": {
        "title": "xxx",
        "text": "xxx",
        "tags": {
          "audience": {
            "1": {
              "name": "xxx",
              "title": "xxx",
              "id": "xxx"
            }
          },
          "styleHint": {
            "1": {
              "name": "xxx",
              "title": "xxx",
              "id": "xxx"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "title": "xxx",
      "text": "xxx",
      "tags": {
        "audience": {
          "1": {
            "name": "xxx",
            "title": "xxx",
            "id": "xxx"
          }
        },
        "styleHint": {
          "1": {
            "name": "xxx",
            "title": "xxx",
            "id": "xxx"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "2": {
      "title": "xxx",
      "text": "xxx",
      "tags": {
        "audience": {
          "1": {
            "name": "xxx",
            "title": "xxx",
            "id": "xxx"
          }
        },
        "styleHint": {
          "1": {
            "name": "xxx",
            "title": "xxx",
            "id": "xxx"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "title": "xxx",
    "text": "xxx",
    "tags": {
      "audience": {
        "1": {
          "name": "xxx",
          "title": "xxx",
          "id": "xxx"
        },
        "2": {
          "name": "xxx",
          "title": "xxx",
          "id": "xxx"
        }
      },
      "styleHint": {
        "1": {
          "name": "xxx",
          "title": "xxx",
          "id": "xxx"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "2": {
    "title": "xxx",
    "text": "xxx",
    "tags": {
      "audience": {
        "1": {
          "name": "xxx",
          "title": "xxx",
          "id": "xxx"
        }
      },
      "styleHint": {
        "1": {
          "name": "xxx",
          "title": "xxx",
          "id": "xxx"
        }
      }
    },
    "anchor":"xxx"

  },
  "3": {
    "1": {
      "title": "xxx",
      "text": "xxx",
      "tags": {
        "audience": {
          "tag": {
            "name": "xxx",
            "title": "xxx",
            "id": "xxx"
          }
        },
        "styleHint": {
          "tag": {
            "name": "xxx",
            "title": "xxx",
            "id": "xxx"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "title": "xxx",
    "text": "xxx",
    "tags": {
      "audience": {
        "1": {
          "name": "xxx",
          "title": "xxx",
          "id": "xxxx"
        }
      },
      "styleHint": {
        "1": {
          "name": "xx",
          "title": "xxx",
          "id": "xxxx"
        }
      }
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: The keys in JSON should be treated as unordered. Why do you want their serialization order?

Comment: requirement is to parse the JSON into a POJO...and specific tags need to be in order..the same order reflects in an XML generated with the POJO values

Comment: Why do you say "keys are returned in reverse order" if you "understand JSONObject is unordered"? Please clarify the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: If the order of properties in a JSON object matters, you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Then that would be the fault of the algorithm that converts the JSON  to POJO. It should convert by name (or by a key annotation), not by the definition order. Is that algorithm yours?

Comment: @PaulBellora I have updated my question to answer yours

Comment: @JanDvorak blame it on gson then :) Have not algo of my own

Comment: @HungryForKnowledge Strange, your code looks like org.json, not gson.

Comment: If keys like "1", "2", ... imply an order, the data would be better packaged as a JSON array instead of an object.

Comment: @PaulBellora yes its orj.json..sorry

Comment: @Henry I need to get the text,title and audience name extracted from this json..array works fine for audience name..what about text and title

Comment: @HungryForKnowledge you can have an array of objects, where each object has two string properties and one array property. Also note arrays normally start at zero.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSONObject : Why JSONObject changing the order of attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17229418/jsonobject-why-jsonobject-changing-the-order-of-attributes)

Answer (score 0):

How about that

Get your org.json.JSONObject source and change these

```
public ListIterator keys() {
    ListIterator iter = new ArrayList(this.keySet()).listIterator();
    return iter;
}
```

and

```
/**
 * Construct an empty JSONObject.
 */
public JSONObject() {
    this.map = new LinkedHashMap();
}
```

and

```
/**
 * The map where the JSONObject's properties are kept.
 */
private final LinkedHashMap map;
```

and

```
public JSONObject(Map map) {
    this.map = new LinkedHashMap();
    if (map != null) {
        Iterator i = map.entrySet().iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry e = (Map.Entry) i.next();
            Object value = e.getValue();
            if (value != null) {
                this.map.put(e.getKey(), wrap(value));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope I don't burn in hell for that.