# Wrong arrangement of data from 'for loop'

Tags: android, for-loop

I have the following code. I added my text fields dynamically. My desired result shown in Genymotion 5.0 (Google Nexus 5) but when I run my app in other devices/actual device the textfields get shuffled. Please help, Thanks in advance.

`JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(question.getSublabels());
            final EditText[] editTextSublabels = new EditText[jsonObject.length()];
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonObject.length(); i++) {
                String names = jsonObject.names().get(i).toString();
                editTextSublabels[i] = (EditText) LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.sublabels, null);
                editTextSublabels[i].setId(i);
                editTextSublabels[i].setHint(jsonObject.getString(names));
                sublabelsContainers.addView(editTextSublabels[i], params);
            }`

[image: Result in Devices]

Comment: maybe you should try to use the addView() with the index parameter, and make the index parameter i like so sublabelsContainers.addView(editTextSublabels[i],i, params); maybe that will work across devices, im not to sure though

Comment: Refer to this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17229418/jsonobject-why-jsonobject-changing-the-order-of-attributes

Comment: @JRowan still the same. :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON order mixed up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948206/json-order-mixed-up)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot and should not rely on the ordering of elements within a JSON object.
In JSON, an object is defined thus:

> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs.

If you want order to be preserved, you need to redefine your data structure or put it inside a jsonarray

see http://www.json.org.

Answer (score 1):

A JSONObject is a type of map.  It does not preserve ordering.  If you want to preserve ordering using JSON, you will need to use an array (and matching `JSONArray` in Java).