# JSON: Order of items

Tags: java, json

I am using a servlet that returns a JSONArray of JSONObjects via URL:

http://myserver.corp:8080/webtools/myServlet?targetDB=myTargetDB&sqlStatement=myStatement&param0=abc

Output:

```
[
    {
        "attribute1": "value1",
        "attribute2": "value2",
        "attribute3": "value3",
        "attribute4": "value4",
    }
]
```

Now this works like a charm, until I discovered that the order attributes varies depending on the environment I launch it in.

When I am launching the program in Eclipse, I get the above result - but when launching the program as a runnable JAR, the order is reversed (attribute4 to attribute1).

Now I understand that JSONObjects are not ordered. But there must be a reason why the order of the attributes in the JSONObjects is reversed.

Does anyone have an idea ?

Cheers,
Tim

Comment: Who knows? My guess it that they're being stored in something like a `HashMap` and then written in iteration order.

Comment: Because JSONs are not ordered. If you want them to be ordered, use a list. There is no meaning to the question because what you see when you print a **representation** of the objects is not the objects order. It **has no order**.

Comment: @ReutSharabani 's comment is the answer of this question. If you want to order the items, do it at client side.

Comment: I know - thanks. My main interrogation was that I did not just get any order, but the exact reverse order (consistently). I will now check the names of the keys while iterating through them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON order mixed up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948206/json-order-mixed-up)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://json.org (my emphasis):

> An object is an *unordered* set of name/value pairs.

So this

```
{ "foo": 1, "bar": 2 }
```

and this

```
{ "bar": 2, "foo": 1 }
```

is *the same* object. Any library that is looking for an order is looking for something that does and can not exist. Code can output a JSON object in any order it pleases.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicated: [JSONObject : Why JSONObject changing the order of attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17229418/jsonobject-why-jsonobject-changing-the-order-of-attributes#answer-17230191)

If you use [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) you can order fields in your class, if your object is a Java POJO

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "attribute1", "attribute2", "attribute3"})
public class Attributes { ... }
```

Comment: I know there is no problem. The object created will be the same. equals and hashcode will be the same.

But he just asks for the order anyway, so I answer with a possibility with other tool.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem :

Go on class `JSONObject`
On the method : `public JSONObject()`
change `this.map = new LinkedHashMap();`

LinkedHashMap will iterate in the order in which the entries were put into the map

```
/**
     * Construct an empty JSONObject.
     */
    public JSONObject() {
        this.map = new LinkedHashMap();
    }
```