# Android Volley JSONObjectRequest Changes JSON Objects Order

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley, jsonobjectrequest

The jsonObjectRequest is from this url:

https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=BCC,BTC,DASH,ETH&tsyms=USD

Which returns this json object when you go to that url:

```
{"BCC":{"USD":13091},"BTC":{"USD":6783.54},"DASH":{"USD":274.53},"ETH": 
{"USD":531.81}}
```

However jsonObjectRequest returns the response:

```
{"ETH":{"USD":530.83},"BCC":{"USD":13091},"DASH":{"USD":274.36},"BTC": 
{"USD":6783.94}}
```

Code:

```
private void volleyRequest(List<String> coins) {

    String url = "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=BCC,BTC,DASH,ETH";

    String currency = "&tsyms=USD";

    url += currency;

    Log.i("URL2", url);

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.i("Response", response.toString());
                    try {
                        JSONArray keys = response.names();
                        for (int i = 0; i < keys.length(); i++) {
                            String key = keys.getString(i);
                            Double value = response.getJSONObject(key).getDouble("USD");
                            mCoins.add(new Coin(key, value));
                        }

                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });

    mCoins.clear();

    MySingleton.getInstance(getContext()).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

Logs:

URL before JSON Object Request

```
 I/URL2: https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=BCC,BTC,DASH,ETH&tsyms=USD
```

JSONObject response

```
 I/Response: {"ETH":{"USD":530.83},"BCC":{"USD":13091},"DASH":{"USD":274.36},"BTC":{"USD":6783.94}}
```

This only happens on older versions of android.
Problem does not occur for API 25 occurs at API 19.

Why is this happening and how to solve this?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/a/17229462/5217712

Comment: There's nothing to resolve because JSON has no ordering. If you care about order, then sort `mCoins` or the keys of the JSON yourself

Comment: It is not a bug. JSON object fields have no order, as they are not array or list, but a map.