# Order mismatch from RestAssured Response object to JSON conversion

Tags: rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I got a Rest Assured Response object. While trying to convert from Response object to JSON. The conversation happen successfully but JSON order is mismatch. It would be great if some one assist on this.

Conversion:

```
JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(restAssuredResponse.getBody());
```

Comment: The order does not matter, as we get the JSON value using key.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17229418/jsonobject-why-jsonobject-changing-the-order-of-attributes

Answer (score 0):

Basically, JSON is an unordered set of key value pairs. Which, for any JSON object the order of key/value pairs shouldn't be considered.

The JSON Object should be considered equal even if the order is not the same.