# Electronjs manipulate json object and reorder its keys internally

Tags: javascript, json, sorting, electron

I am using electronjs for a new application, and I have a json object 
`jsonData` with string elements that contain numbers (Here is the index file):
 `index.html`

```
     <html>
  <head> 
    <title>Test Json Sorting Order</title>
    <meta  charset="utf-8"/> 
    <script> 
     const {ipcRenderer } = require('electron');
     let jsonData = { 
            "3_01":"element301",
            "2_5": 'element05',
            '2_10': 'element10',
            "2_11": 'element11',
            '2_13': 'element13',
            '2_1': 'element01',
            '2_2': 'element02',
            '2_4': 'element04',
            '2_14': 'element14',
            '2_15': 'element15',
         }; 

     window.onload = function () {
        let elemV = document.getElementById('testVanilla'); 
        for (let i in  jsonData)
            elemV.innerHTML += i +   "<br /> ";  
     }
     ipcRenderer.send('MsgOne', jsonData);
     ipcRenderer.once('MsgOne-reply', (event, json) => {
        let elemE = document.getElementById('testElectron');

        for (let i in  json)
            elemE.innerHTML += i  + "<br />" ;
     });

</script>
  </head>
  <body> 
  <h2> Vanilla Javascript Example output </h2>
  <div id = "testVanilla">  </div>
  <h2> ElectronJs Example output </h2>
  <div id = "testElectron">  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and here is the `main.js` file

```
 const {app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain} = require('electron') 
 const path = require('path');
 const startUrl = path.resolve(__dirname + path.sep + 'index.html');
 let win

function createWindow () {
  win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600}) 
win.loadURL(startUrl); 
 win.webContents.openDevTools(); 
  win.on('closed', function () { 
    win = null
  })
} 
app.on('ready', createWindow)

ipcMain.on('MsgOne',(event, arg) => {  
 event.sender.send('MsgOne-reply', arg);
})
```

when I want to send this data object from ipcMain to ipcRenderer or vise versa, 
electronjs will reorder the object by his own way and give out this result:

`2_1,2_10,2_11,2_13,2_14,2_15,2_2,2_4,2_5,3_01`

electron is known to serialize the arguments in JSON internally . 
So, I tried to apply the same code using vanilla javascript to display the same object, 
and I got the same order as the original object , using serialized object or non-serialized:

`3_01,2_5,2_10,2_11,2_13,2_1,2_2,2_4,2_14,2_15`

How to prevent electronjs from manipulating the object internally to get the exact original object

Comment: This is not an array. It's not even a valid an object. An array would have square brackets (`[]`)....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON Object isn't supposed to keep the same order.

[Check this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17229462)