# influxdb - order of columns

Tags: python-3.x, influxdb, influxdb-python

I am writing measurement to influxdb with `InfluxDBClient` library

```
entry = [{
            "time": int((self.end)),
            "measurement": "measurement1",
            "fields": {
                "eventId": self.eventId,
                "start": self.start,
                "end": self.end,
                "lifetime": self.lifetime,
            },
```

I have noticed that the db is not respecting given order of columns, instead the `time` is first and then column names in alphabetical order

```
>SELECT * FROM "measurement1" 
time end eventId hostName lifetime start
```

How to enforce order given in entry?

Comment: I am not sure that it is possible, because server returns JSON and JSON objects (dictionaries) are not strictly ordered. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17229462/4265407

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your using InfluxQL there is no option to sort the results other than the time field

If you are using [flux](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/flux/guides/sort-limit/) in then it possible to sort the query results.

```
from(bucket:"db/rp")
  |> range(start:-12h)
  |> filter(fn: (r) =>
    r._measurement == "system" and
    r._field == "uptime"
  )
  |> sort(columns:["region", "host", "_value"])
```