# Convert XML to JSON but the content not correct with jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, xml, json

I am using the [jQuery plugin](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/xml-to-json/) to convert the XML content to JSON, but I found that the ordering of JSON content is not correct:

XML:

```
<list>
    <row>
        <item>interest</item>
        <item>7</item>
        <item>10</item>
        <item>13</item>
        <item>15</item>
        <item>20</item>
        <item>25</item>
        <item>30</item>
    </row>
    <row>
        <item>1.000</item>
        <item>$8,631.87</item>
        <item>$6,132.29</item>
        <item>$4,787.03</item>
        <item>$4,189.46</item>
        <item>$3,219.26</item>
        <item>$2,638.11</item>
        <item>$2,251.48</item>
    </row>
    <row>
        <item>1.630</item>
        <item>$8,823.44</item>
        <item>$6,325.61</item>
        <item>$4,982.41</item>
        <item>$4,386.29</item>
        <item>$3,419.83</item>
        <item>$2,842.51</item>
        <item>$2,459.75</item>
    </row>
    <row>
        <itemb>2.150</itemb>
        <item>$8,983.59</item>
        <item>$6,488.07</item>
        <item>$5,147.43</item>
        <item>$4,553.07</item>
        <item>$3,591.13</item>
        <itemhl>$3,018.36</itemhl>
        <item>$2,640.16</item>
    </row>
</list>
```

The converted JSON object:

```
{
  "list": {
    "row": [
      {
        "item": [
          "interest",
          "7",
          "10",
          "13",
          "15",
          "20",
          "25",
          "30"
        ]
      },
      {
        "item": [
          "1.000",
          "$8,631.87",
          "$6,132.29",
          "$4,787.03",
          "$4,189.46",
          "$3,219.26",
          "$2,638.11",
          "$2,251.48"
        ]
      },
      {
        "item": [
          "1.630",
          "$8,823.44",
          "$6,325.61",
          "$4,982.41",
          "$4,386.29",
          "$3,419.83",
          "$2,842.51",
          "$2,459.75"
        ]
      },
      {
        "itemb": "2.150",
        "item": [
          "$8,983.59",
          "$6,488.07",
          "$5,147.43",
          "$4,553.07",
          "$3,591.13",
          "$2,640.16"
        ],
        "itemhl": "$3,018.36"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

According to the XML, it is `itemb`, `item`, `item`, `item`, `item`, `item`, `itemhl`, `item`, but the JSON is `itemb`, `item`, `item`, `item`, `item`, `item`, `item`, `itemhl`. Could someone please suggest how to fix it, thanks.

Comment: Is there some specific reason you want it as an object rather than an xml document?

Comment: *"Could someone please suggest how to fix it, thanks."* how would you expect it to be handled instead?

Comment: JSON key's don't have to be ordered in any particular way. See similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948206/json-order-mixed-up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have 2 key-value pairs with the same key in JSON.

I believe what you want is the following, but that is not technically possible to my knowledge.

```
{
    "itemb": "2.150",
    "item": [
      "$8,983.59",
      "$6,488.07",
      "$5,147.43",
      "$4,553.07",
      "$3,591.13"
    ],
    "itemhl": "$3,018.36",
    "item": "$2,640.16"
  }
```

Comment: ok, so the solution is read the `XML` directly without converting it to `JSON`