# Parse JSON in it's order the way it is

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I am parsing a JSON file with weekdays and times inside those weekdays. Problem is that whenever I parse them, it's a huge mix up.
For example this is my json file:

```
{
"root1": {
"test": {
  "monday": {
    "08:00-12:20": {
      "value1": "value2",
      "value3": "value4"
    }
  },
  "tuesday": {
    "08:00-11:50": {
      "value1": "value2",
      "value3": "value4"
    }
  },
  "wednesday": {
    "08:00-11:50": {
      "value1": "value2",
      "value3": "value4"
    }
  },
  "friday": {
    "08:00-11:50": {
      "value1": "value2",
      "value3": "value4"
    }
  }
},
"test2": {
  "saturday": {
    "08:05-11:00": {
      "value1": "value2",
      "value3": "value4"
    }
  }
},
"test3": {
  "monday": {
    "12:45-15:10": {
      "value1": "value2",
      "value3": "value4"
    }
  },
  "tuesday": {
    "08:55-11:50": {
      "value1": "value2",
      "value3": "value4"
    },
    "15:30-17:55": {
      "value1": "value2",
      "value3": "value4"
    }
  },
  "wednesday": {
    "16:35-18:00": {
      "value1": "value2",
      "value3": "value4"
    }
  },
  "thursday": {
    "08:00-09:40": {
      "value1": "value2",
      "value3": "value4"
    },
    "10:00-12:25": {
      "value1": "value2",
      "value3": "value4"
    }
  },
  "friday": {
    "16:35-18:00": {
      "value1": "value2",
      "value3": "value4"
    }
  }
}
}
}
```

So you see the weekdays are in the correct order. But if I parsed them they're like this for example:

- thursday
- friday
- monday
- wednesday
- tuesday

How can I parse them into the right order?

Comment: Following the JSON specification, [objects are unordered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4920304/1073063).

Comment: Ok thanks. But how can I parse them into the right order? Or sort them?

Comment: You probably can't, unless there is some implementation that doesn't follow the specification. You'll have to order them yourself after parsing the file. If you want ordered results, you should use arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [JsonReader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html) for stream reading - and control order.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use a `JSONArray` instead of a `JSONObject`. In fact the `JSONArray` preserves the order

Comment: Also if that is not an array?

Comment: @Enrichman JSONOBject in a unordered

Comment: I understand the point, but in JSON this is an Object `{..}` and this is an array `[..]`. I don't think you can use a JSONArray to deserialize JSON objects..