# How to order the JSON values in Servlet?

Tags: arrays, json, servlets

I am a new guy for JSON, I don't know to send JSON object and Array...

But, I pass the JSON values like the below format,

```
                object.put("code", "1");
                object.put("message", "Success");
                object.put("Name", "xxx");
                object.put("F_Name","yyy");
                object.put("Address", "zzz");
                object.put("Phone_No","123");


                out.println(object);
```

But it display like

```
{"Phone_No":"123","message":"Success","Address":"zzz","Name":"xxx","F_Name":"yyy","code":"1"}
```

I don't know, why it's display like this. How to order this? Please help me.

And this is what format, Array format or object format...

And tell how to send array values in JSON..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON order mixed up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948206/json-order-mixed-up)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't write what is the class of the `object`. However, if you care about the order, use [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) and its [`JsonObject`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html) class:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

JsonObject object = new JsonObject();
object.addProperty("code", "1");
object.addProperty("message", "success");
object.addProperty("Name", "xxx");
// ...

Gson gson = new Gson();
out.println(gson.toJson(object));
```

Comment: I am using this org.json-20120521.jar library, and use same JsonObject object = new JsonObject(); but this library not have the gson property, can i must need this com.google.gson.Gson for ordering json values.

Comment: You are using different library. Try `gson-2.2.4.jar` from [this zip](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/detail?name=google-gson-2.2.4-release.zip&can=2&q=).

Answer (score 1):

As my understanding of question and the code above, The "object" you already using might be json object. Usually JSON object can maintain data in the form of key, value pairs. So you are putting content into json object and displaying. That's why its getting displayed like that. The displayed format is json format. If you want to put array into json object you can put as you already did for normal strings.

```
   object.put("array1", arrayvariable1[]);
   object.put("array2", arrayvariable2[]);
```

I guess it might have helped you.