# Serialize sub-class after super-class?

Tags: java, gson

I cannot find any documentation on this, but it seems Gson serializes fields of sub-class before those of the super-class:

```
class G9 {
  static  class B { String s1 = "1"; String s2 = "2"; }
  static class C extends B { String s3 = "3"; }
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(new C()));
  }
}
```

This program produces the following output:

```
/cygdrive/c/Java/jdk1.8.0/bin/javac -classpath gson-2.1.jar -g G9.java  && /cygdrive/c/Java/jdk1.8.0/bin/java -classpath ".;gson-2.1.jar" G9
{"s3":"3","s1":"1","s2":"2"}
```

I would like it to be the following:

```
{"s1":"1","s2":"2","s3":"3"}
```

I realize I can do this with a [`TypeAdapter`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html) but that essentially amounts to

- implementing serialization
- figuring out how to delegate deserialization to `Gson` OR implementing that as well.

Is there an easier way to achieve this? I guess I am looking for a `new FieldOrderingTypeAdapter<C>(C.class, "s1", "s2", "s3")` or `GsonBuilder.setFieldOrder("s1", "s2", "s3")` or something.

I am using `Gson 2.1`.

Comment: The point is, even if you somehow specify the order that should be used to generate the fields, the JSON output may not reflect that order.  The order of the elements in a JSON "object" cannot be specified or controlled.

Comment: @HotLicks, I think the key phrase here is "may not reflect". I confess I have not tested with a `TypeAdapter` but rather assumed that the produced json string will match the order of `JsonWriter.write` calls, probably based on experience with other serializing. Do you know that to be false?

Comment: It might match the order today and not tomorrow.  To depend on it would be foolishness (unless the tool actually specs that behavior).

Comment: @HotLicks or I could change to a different library later. I respect your concern but "foolish" is rather strong, don't you think?

Answer (score 1):

From [JSON order mixed up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948206/json-order-mixed-up):

> You cannot and should not rely on the ordering of elements within a
>   JSON object.
>
> From the JSON specification at http://www.json.org/
>
> ```
>  An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs
> ```
>
> As a consequence, JSON libraries are free to rearrange the order of
>   the elements as they see fit. This is not a bug.

As far as I know, there is no simple way to get around this.

Comment: I did not think it was a bug. The reality is that the file has to be read by human beings -- support, developers. It will be good to be able to see it in a natural order and the library would not be non-compliant if it allows specifying the order