# In a POST does order of JSON variables matter?

Tags: java, json, post

Im writing a program to upload my companies orders to an order review site through a POST request. It takes a JSON Object, and it starts like this

```
{
 "utoken": "XVUYvqaRLPtjfuj1OyNbyqw1cv0R0f76g4PadwmR",
 "platform": "general",
```

However when I create my JSONObject using JSON.simple

```
JSONObject test = new JSONObject();
test.put("utoken", "awooga");
test.put("platform", "general");
```

It puts it into alphabetical order when I print it out

```
{
  "platform": "general",
  "utoken": "awooga"
```

Does this matter? I dont think it should, but just want to make certain as I've never ran into this before.

Comment: order does not matter.

Comment: It should not matter if you access the object's properties by key name.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON order mixed up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948206/json-order-mixed-up)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As per [JSON standard](http://json.org/), official definition of object states:

> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs.

Therefore the order does not matter. Obviously from the perspective of the server receiving the POST request, the order can be parsed from HTTP header and reacted upon. I suppose however this is not of your interest, as it does not make much sense to do so.

Answer (score -1):

See an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948206/json-order-mixed-up)

TL;DR - order isn't promised to stay the same