# How to parse Json using Java?

Tags: java, arrays, json

I want to parse a json object in java.The json file is `{"l1":"1","l2":"0","f1":"0","connected":"0","all":"0"}`
i am trying to write a java program to print above json as

```
l1=1
l2=0
f1=0
connected=0
all=0
```

The number of entries in the json file can be increased, so i have to loop through the json and print all data. This is what i've done so far.

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            URL url = new URL("http://localhost/switch.json");
            JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(url.openStream());
            JSONObject root = new JSONObject(tokener);
            JSONArray jsonArray = root.names();
            if (jsonArray != null) { 
               int len = jsonArray.length();
               for (int i=0;i<len;i++){ 
                  System.out.println(jsonArray.get(i).toString());
               } 
            }   
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error Occured");
        }
    }
}
```

the above program can only print the first item of each array. But i am trying get the result i mentioned in the beginning. Can anybody help ??

Comment: I am using a library from json.org.

Comment: Show us an example of such a JSON array. Right now you parse an object, not an array. Show us the code you use to parse an array of objects.

Comment: i just want to parse this {"l1":"1","l2":"0","f1":"0","connected":"0","all":"0"}. I have added the code used in the question.

Comment: If it starts with ```{``` and ends with ```}```, that is a JavaScript/JSON Object, not an Array; JavaScript Arrays use ```[``` and ```]```, and do not need ```:``` to separate keys and values.

Comment: Sorry ive edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is simple JSON object, **not an array**. You need to iterate through keys and print data:

```
    JSONObject root = new JSONObject(tokener);
    Iterator<?> keys = root.keys();

    while(keys.hasNext()){
        String key = (String)keys.next();
        System.out.println(key + "=" + root.getString(key));
    }
```

Please note that above solution prints keys in a random order, due to usage of `HashMap` internally. Please refer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948206/json-order-mixed-up) describing this behavior.

Comment: error : can only iterate over an array or any instance or java.lang.iterable

Comment: Why the array is printing in random order ?? I got output as connected=0
all=0
l1=1
l2=1
f1=0

Comment: Because values are stored in a HashMap internally, so keys are not ordered.

Answer (score 4):

Your JSON file does not contain an array - it contains an object.

JSON arrays are enclosed in `[]` brackets; JSON objects are enclosed in `{}` brackets.

```
[1, 2, 3]                     // array
{ one:1, two:2, three:3 }     // object
```

Your code currently extracts the names from this object, then prints those out:

```
JSONObject root = new JSONObject(tokener);
JSONArray jsonArray = root.names();
```

Instead of looping over just the names, you need to use the names (keys) to extract each value from the object:

```
JSONObject root = new JSONObject(tokener);
for (Iterator<?> keys= root.keys(); keys.hasNext();){
  System.out.println(key + "=" + root.get(keys.next()));
}
```

Note that the entries will not print out in any particular order, because [JSON objects](http://json.org/) are not ordered:

> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs  -- http://json.org/

See also the [documentation](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html) for the JSONObject class.

Comment: error : can only iterate over an array or any instance or java.lang.iterable

Comment: It's the same error, but I didn't see your answer until afterwards, so too late to avoid! Shame the library doesn't implement Iterable...