# How to put object into JSONObject properly?

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to fill my JSONObject like this:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("Command", "CreateNewUser");
json.put("User", user);
```

`user` is instance of basic class that contains fields like "FirstName", "LastName" etc.

Looks like I'm doing it wrong, because I get JSON like this:

```
{
    "Command":"CreateNewUser",
    "User":"my.package.name.classes.User@2686a150"
}
```

instead of "tree".

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: Well... no library at all. I'm using vanilla Android SDK.

Comment: user object returns the override method toString() of the basic class of java , which return "Class-Name+@+Hash-Code" ...you need to pass hashmap instead or other Collections...

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Since you use `JSONObject` to represent non-primitive types, any instance passed to `JSONObject.put(Object, Object)` will generate nested items (or *trees*).

```
JSONObject main = new JSONObject();
main.put("Command", "CreateNewUser");
JSONObject user = new JSONObject();
user.put("FirstName", "John");
user.put("LastName", "Reese");
main.put("User", user);
```

```
{
    "User": {
        "FirstName": "John",
        "LastName": "Reese"
    },
    "Command": "CreateNewUser"
}
```

Comment: Why is "User" before "Command" even though main.put("Command", "CreateNewUser"); comes before main.put("User", user);

Comment: @mostvenerablesir Because, [per JSON spec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4920304/3453226), an object is an _unordered_ set of name/value pairs. Therefore, the order of elements may be rearranged as needed.

Comment: ok you just write it in the reverse order to what the code would generate?

Comment: @mostvenerablesir No, that is the result of calling [`main.toString(4)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#toString(int)). The library itself has rearranged the order of elements for performance reasons, since it is not required to preserve their insertion order.

Answer (score 10):

This will do what you want !

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("Command", "CreateNewUser");
json.put("User", new JSONObject(user));
```

Answer (score 5):

The framework you are using does not know how to convert your User object to a Map, that is used internally as JSON representation and so it is using standard 'toString' method that you have not overriden.

Just export all properties (for example write method 'Map toMap()' on your User type ) of your User to a Map (all values must be standard JDK types) and put that map in your json object:

```
json.put("User", user.toMap())
```

It will do the thing.

Answer (score 1):

From http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#put

```
 public JSONObject put (String name, Object value)
```

> Parameters
>   value a JSONObject, JSONArray, String, Boolean, Integer, Long, Double,  NULL, or null. May not be NaNs or infinities.

Though your `user` is subclass of `Object`, it is not the type that the `put` method expects.

The android SDK's implementation of `JSONObject` seems lacking a `put(java.lang.String key, java.util.Map value)` method (from the same link above). You may need to add a method `toMap()` in your `user` class to convert it into a `HashMap`. Then finally use `json.put("user", new JSONObject(user.toMap()));`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it using fasterxml ObjectMapper.

```
ObjectMapper o = new ObjectMapper();
String userJsonString = o.readValueAsString(user);

JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
jsonObj.put("Command", "CreateNewUser");
jsonObj.put("User", new JSONObject(userJsonString));
```

You will get following output:

```
{
    "User": {
        "FirstName": "John",
        "LastName": "Reese"
    },
    "Command": "CreateNewUser"
}
```

Ref: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/