# Append a json object to another json object java

Tags: java, json

I have a two json objects

```
JSONObject org_query = new JSONObject("{\"query\": {\"bool\": {\"must\": [], \"must_not\": [], \"should\": []}}}");

JSONObject query_form = new JSONObject("{\"match_phrase\": {\"Sales Channel\": \"Online\"}}");
```

I want to append the second object to first one inside the key `must` and form a new JSON object.

Required Output:

```
{"query":{"bool":{"must_not":[],"should":[],"must":[{"match_phrase": {"Sales Channel": "Online"}}]}}}
```

I tried this,

```
org_query["query"]["bool"]["must"].append(query_form);
```

But shows error.

```
array type expected found org.json.jsonarray java
```

How to make it

Comment: What error? Your second json is not valid.

Comment: Looks like elasticsearch queries... Why not use their Java sdk?

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can do:

```
org_query = org_query.put("query", org_query.getJSONObject("query").put("bool", org_query.getJSONObject("query").getJSONObject("bool").append("must", query_form)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure which API you're using but a quick search on Google yielded this result:

The `.append` method is for adding values into an array.

Try using `.put` method. This is for adding values to a property by key.

Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/maf242/mobile/api-ref/oracle/adfmf/json/JSONObject.html

For more examples, see this other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30006004/7119882

Comment: Thanks... I found that... `org_query.getJSONObject("query").getJSONObject("bool").getJSONArray("must").put(query_form);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use small [json](https://github.com/antonsjava/json) library

```
JsonValue org_query = JsonParser.parse("{\"query\": {\"bool\": {\"must\": [], \"must_not\": [], \"should\": []}}}");
JsonValue query_form = JsonParser.parse("{\"match_phrase\": {\"Sales Channel\": \"Online\"}}");
JsonValue must = org_query.findFirst(SPM.path("query", "bool", "must"));
must.asArray().add(query_form);
String result = org_query.toCompactString();
```