# json.dumps messes up order

Tags: python, json

I'm working with the [json module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) creating a `json` file containing entries of the like

```
json.dumps({"fields": { "name": "%s", "city": "%s", "status": "%s", "country": "%s" }})
```

However, in the `json`-file created the fields are in the wrong order

```
{"fields": {"status": "%s", "city": "%s", "name": "%s", "country": "%s"}}
```

which is a problem because the substitions for the `%s`-strings are now incorrect.

How can I force the `dumps` function to keep the given order?

Comment: Python dictionaries have no order.

Comment: @Klaus D. Yet `OrderedDict`s do have it (see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43640347/237105) below)

Comment: I had the same issue with python2. Python 3 fixed it for me.

Comment: For posterity, python dictionaries are ordered as of 3.6: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2016-September/146327.html

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Like the other answers correctly state, before Python 3.6, dictionaries are *unordered*.

That said, [JSON is also supposed to have *unordered* mappings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4920304/42973), so in principle it does not make much sense to store ordered dictionaries in JSON. Concretely, this means that upon reading a JSON object, the order of the returned keys can be arbitrary.

A good way of preserving the order of a mapping (like a Python OrderedDict) in JSON is therefore to output an array of (key, value) pairs that you convert back to an ordered mapping upon reading:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> import json
>>> d = OrderedDict([(1, 10), (2, 20)])                                         
>>> print d[2]
20
>>> json_format = json.dumps(d.items())                   
>>> print json_format  # Order maintained
[[1, 10], [2, 20]]
>>> OrderedDict(json.loads(json_format))  # Reading from JSON: works!
OrderedDict([(1, 10), (2, 20)])
>>> _[2]  # This works!
20
```

(Note the way the ordered dictionary is constructed from a *list* of (key, value) pairs: `OrderedDict({1: 10, 2: 20})` would not work: its keys are not necessarily ordered as in the dictionary literal, since the literal creates a Python dictionary whose keys are unordered.)

**PS**: Starting with Python 3.1, the json modules [offers a hook](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) for automatically converting a list of pairs (like above) to something else like an OrderedDict.

Comment: Even though JSON is unordered, it would still be useful to have an ordered abstraction for it in the json library, for the same reasons that OrderedDict is useful. For instance, I want to output some JSON objects for both human and machine readability, and I want to preserve a particular key order for the human aspect.

Comment: @John B There's a mechanism for that, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43640347/237105) below.

Comment: One reason to have consistent ordering is if you need to generate a JSON response and then build a hash for use in an ETag or a cache. In this case we don't need it to be in a specific order, but we do need it to be in a consistent and reproducible order. Each time you call it you should get the same string. json.dumps(d, sort_keys=True) will accomplish that.

Comment: Fly in the ointment: Python 3.6+ dictionaries *are* ordered.

Answer (score 27):

You can choose `OrderedDict` to be used instead of an ordinary `dict` when creating a json object to remember the order of insertions:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> a = '{"fields": { "name": "%s", "city": "%s", "status": "%s", "country": "%s" }}'
>>> b = json.loads(a, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
>>> json.dumps(b)
'{"fields": {"name": "%s", "city": "%s", "status": "%s", "country": "%s"}}'
```

Comment: This is interesting. Is it guaranteed that `json.dumps()` preserves the order of the `OrderedDict` `b`? I can't find anything in the documentation.

Comment: @EOL `items = dct.items()`, line 355 in Lib/json/encoder.py (python3.6). I can't think of a way or reason for json lib to scramble this order.

Comment: Me neither, but it would be nice to officially guarantee it in the documentation (for the current and future versions of the `json` module), especially since JSON itself does not have any concept of ordered set of key/value pairs (http://json.org).

Comment: I created a documentation enhancement request: http://bugs.python.org/issue30550.

Answer (score 15):

This is a dictionary, and dictionaries don't keep order.
You can use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead.

You could also add the sort_keys=False parameter:

```
json.dumps(values, sort_keys=False)
```

Comment: This is good for writing JSON, but not for reading: JSON mappings have no order, i.e., the mapping that you read from JSON is not guaranteed to be ordered as in the JSON file.

Comment: I guess you meant `dumps` instead of `loads`? In fact, `loads` does not have any `sort_keys` argument, by default.

Comment: You are right. I meant 'dumps' and not 'loads'. Sorry for that. I will edit this

Comment: sort_keys already defaults to False, so this doesn't change anything. json.dumps will not preserve the order of keys from the supplied OrderedDict

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create an OrderedDict from a dict because order has already changed the moment you create a dictionary.So best way is to use tuples to create a OrderedDict

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import json

a = (("name","foo"),("city","bar"),("status","baz"),("country","my"))

b = OrderedDict(a)

c = {"fileds": b}

print json.dumps(c)
Output:
{"fileds": {"name": "foo", "city": "bar", "status": "baz", "country": "my"}}
```

Comment: JSON has no concept of ordered mapping, so dumping the OrderedDict `b` to JSON can change the key order, in principle. You must dump the `.items()` of the OrderedDict, as in my answer. Furthermore, there is no need for the indirection you added with the `c` variable: it has no effect (but to complicate the code).

Answer (score 2):

Python 3.6.1:

```
Python 3.6.1 (default, Oct 10 2020, 20:16:48)
[GCC 7.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import json
>>> json.dumps({'b': 1, 'a': 2})
'{"b": 1, "a": 2}'
```

Python 2.7.5:

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Nov 20 2015, 02:00:19) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import json
>>> json.dumps({'b': 1, 'a': 2})
'{"a": 2, "b": 1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you created the ordered dict, then after `json.loads`, you can use template of the ordered dict to recreate it in order.

In summary use:

```py
ordered_dict = copy.deepcopy(sample_dict)
ordered_dict.update(unordered_dict)
```

In this working example, there is a list of ordered dict that were just retrieved with `json.loads`:

```py
def convert_json_to_ordered(unordered_dicts):
    """ json.dumps() doesn't save ordered dicts in order. """
    sample_list = music_treeview()
    sample_dict = sample_list[0]  # ordered key/value pairs
    ordered_dicts = []
    for unordered in unordered_dicts:
        ordered = copy.deepcopy(sample_dict)
        ordered.update(unordered)
        ordered_dicts.append(ordered)
    return ordered_dicts
```