# elasticsearch: define field's order in returned doc

Tags: elasticsearch

i'm doing sending queries to elasticsearch and it responde with an unknown order of fields in its documents.
how can i fix the order that elsasticsearch is returning fields inside documents?
i mean, i'm sending this query:

```
{
"index": "my_index",
"_source":{
          "includes" : ["field1","field2","field3","field14"]
  },
"size": X,
"body": {
    "query": { 
        // stuff    
       }
    }
}
```

and when it responds, it gives me something not in the good order.
i ultimatly want to convert this to csv, and want to fix csv headers.
is there something to do so i can get something like 
doc1 :{"field1","field2","field3","field14"}
doc2 :{"field1","field2","field3","field14"}
...
in the same order as my "_source" ?

thank's for your help.

Answer (score 0):

A document in Elasticsearch is a JSON hash/map and by definition [maps are unordered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4920304/4604579).

One solution around this would be to use [Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/index.html) in order to extract docs from ES using an [`elasticsearch` input](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-elasticsearch.html) and output them in CSV using a [`csv` output](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-csv.html). That way you can guarantee that the fields in the CSV file will have the exact same order as specified. Another benefit is that you don't have to write your own boilerplate code to extract from ES and sink to CSV, Logstash does it all for you for free.

The Logstash configuration would look something like this:

```
input {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "localhost"
    query => '{ "query": { "match_all": {} } }'
    size => 100
    index => "my_index"
  }
}
filter {}
output {
    csv {
        fields => ["field1","field2","field3","field14"]
        path => "/path/to/file.csv"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Val. thank you for your answer. i understand your proposition but i don't want to install logstash only for ordering fields. i can't beleive there's no a native way to do that with elasticsearch. do someone has another solution to fix this issue? Anyway, thank you Val and have a nice day :)

Comment: It is neither an ES issue nor a shortcoming, it's simply what the JSON spec mandates ;)