# How do I retain order of elements in scala and Json4s

Tags: scala, json4s

I am using JSON4S in Scala to get the toString() of my POJO class in JSON format as follows.

```
//JSON related libraries
import org.json4s.{DefaultFormats, Formats}

//JSON handling support from Scalatra
import org.scalatra.json._

// JSON library for converting the POJO toString as Json
import org.json4s.native.Json

class Customer(val id:Int, var firstName:String, var lastName:String) {

    println("Customer - Constructor  BEGIN .... ")

    def this(firstName:String, lastName:String) {
            this(Customer.inc, firstName, lastName)
    }

    //override def toString = s"Customer [Id=$id, FirstName=$firstName, LastName=$lastName]"

    override def toString = Json(DefaultFormats).write(this)

    println("Customer - Constructor END .... ")
}
```

However when I test this with an instance, the order of elements is distorted as follows.

```
{                                 
   "firstName": "Raghavan",
   "id": 1,                      
   "lastName": "Muthu"        
}
```

What I really want is

```
{                          
   "id": 1,        
   "firstName": "Raghavan",                     
   "lastName": "Muthu"        
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why would you want this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948206/json-order-mixed-up

Comment: @ars, I think and feel it would be more appropriate and sensible if Id comes first and both the names are together in the JSON output.

Comment: See the the question I've attached. "A (JSON) object is an unordered set of name/value pairs" -- it is a quote from the JSON specification.

Comment: @ars, thanks. I got that. I was just thinking is there a simple way to do it in JSON4S like how we used to do in GSON with a LinkedHashMap.