# Haskell - generating JSON with aeson gives incorrect order of fields

Tags: json, haskell, aeson

I am trying to encode a data type into JSON:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}

import Data.Aeson

data Trend = Trend
            { period :: String
            , africa :: String
            , americas :: String
            , asia :: String
            } deriving Show

instance ToJSON Trend where
  toJSON Trend{..} = 
    object [ "Period"    .= period
           , "Africa"    .= africa
           , "Americas"  .= americas
           , "Asia"      .= asia
           ]

test = Trend {period = "2013", africa = "1", americas = "2", asia = "3"}
```

Which gives:

```
λ: encode test
λ: "{\"Asia\":\"3\",\"Period\":\"2013\",\"Africa\":\"1\",\"Americas\":\"2\"}"
```

I don't understand why the generated JSON does not have the fields in the same order as my data type.

I am expecting the output to be {period, africa, americas, asia} and I am getting {asia, period, africa, americas)

I understand that in passing information across, the order is not important but I am curious as to why this is happening.

Comment: JSON has no 'correct' order of fields. edit: see the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948206/json-order-mixed-up)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `toEncoding` method which is available since `aeson-0.10` (use `aeson-0.11` though, if only possible). In that case you have more control over the generated structure:

```
instance ToJSON Trend where
  toJSON Trend{..} = 
    object [ "Period"    .= period
           , "Africa"    .= africa
           , "Americas"  .= americas
           , "Asia"      .= asia
           ]

  toEncoding Trend {..} =
    pairs $ "Period"   .= period
         <> "Africa"   .= africa
         <> "Americas" .= americas
         <> "Asia"     .= asia
```

Or in case as simple is this, is worth using `Generic` derivation

```
instance ToJSON Trend where
    toJSON = genericToJSON defaultOptions { fieldLabelModifier = capitaliseFirst }
      where
        capitaliseFirst (x:xs) = toUpper x : xs
        capitaliseFirst []     = []
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am a bit confused. Should I be putting something in the line `enter code here` ?

Comment: Ah, that was something introduced by inlne editor :S

Comment: do I have to load a particular pragma to use the `toEncoding` ? I get a "series" not in scope  and  is `<>` specific to aeson?

Comment: Sorry once again, it was `pairs`. `<>` comes from `Data.Monoid`

Comment: thanks for this. That works a treat and In fact you have managed to save me a lot of head scratching. I am inclined to tick your answer but I feel it might be unfair to the answer above;  since my question actually only asks why it was going wrong. Much appreciated!

Comment: proved too helpful not to be chosen ;)

Comment: @phadej, will the `genericToJSON` preserve the order??

Comment: @cdupont no, but `genericToEncoding` will.

Comment: @phadej thanks... For my use case I need a Value (in which order matters)... How can I obtain a Value from an Encoding? Thanks again

Answer (score 5):

The reason it is happening is because an Aeson Object is just a HashMap, and when aeson converts the HashMap to text it just serializes the key-value pairs in the order that the HashMap returns them - which probably has no relationship to the order in which the keys were inserted.