# json data save into postgresql become different order

Tags: json, node.js, postgresql, jsonb

When I save data into table , then do select from table it become different order, I check in pgadmin it is too.
Why?? and how to solve it?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "user_role_track"(
    "id" SERIAL NOT NULL,
    "create_date" timestamp without time zone,
    "create_by_user_id" integer,
    "action" integer,
    "old_data" jsonb,
    "new_data" jsonb
  );
```

data create in nodejs app

```
var newData = {
  "id": userRoleId,
  "create_date": timestamp,
  "user_id": userId,
  "role": role
};
... 

// save with promise sync function
var dbQueryR = yield Promise.resolve( queryPromise(dbClient, dbQuery, dbParams) );
```

select from table/ see through pgadmin

```
"{"id": 2, "role": 1, "user_id": 17, "create_date": "2016-07-11 09:09:18"}"
```

Comment: there is no guarantee in the order of the data stored due to the optimisations made by the DBMS. If u need a particular order, you should use `ORDER BY` to fetch the result.

Comment: If you are care about the order of the keys then use `json` instead of `jsonb` type.

Comment: @Abelisto Thanks. but I think jsonb much fit my need

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you rigtht, your json elements are mixed up after insert?..

then look at [json specs](http://www.json.org/)

> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs

as stated in [JSON order mixed up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948206/json-order-mixed-up)

> You cannot and should not rely on the ordering of elements within a
>   JSON object.