# WordPress posts keep changing order Android app

Tags: android-studio, wordpress-rest-api

I am working on an Android application for my Wordpress site, I've added the Rest API plugins in order to be able to get the data in JSON form.

I am using the following URL to get posts

http://mywordpress.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?categories=1&per_page=100

I am using `&per_page=100` because it seems that by default it loads only 10 posts.
My problem is that every time I load posts in my Android app, the posts are displayed in a random order, I am using SwipeRefreshLayout so that I can refresh the posts, but each time I do the refresh the posts are displayed in random ordered, is there a way I can order my posts by date desc?

Answer (score 0):

JSON data can never be relied upon to be in a certain order. Refer to [JSON order mixed up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948206/json-order-mixed-up)

Sort the data to get a certain order.

Comment: Hello Jim, thanks for your answer, actually when i try this url using Postman tool from google, it always show the same order for the posts, but the problem is when loading the posts from my Android app