# mssql query results order not matching the select clause

Tags: sql-server, json, node.js

I'm using npm mssql lib with NodeJS to execute a query from SQL Server with the following query

```
select name, surname, id from clients
```

the query result is correct, (in SQL Server management studio), but the structure of the JSON object returned to the server is mixed like so:

```
{
  surname :"foo",
  id:"bar",
  name:"foo bar"
}
```

How can I tell the SQL Server or the mssql to keep the order of the returned JSON identical to the select clause in the query?

Comment: Not familiar with json, but I don't think this is something you can modify in the SQL query.  It's got to be something in the JS.

Comment: "An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs" - https://stackoverflow.com/a/4920304/4774345