# Creating JSON from String using JSONObject

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to create following Json from a string which is coming from an Excel

```
{
                "RequestId": "1234",
                "OrderID": "NCBTEST02082018-01",
                "Assets": [{
                                "Field1":"1",
                                "Field2": "NCBTEST-01",
                                "Field3": "1",
                                "Field4": "1",
                                "Field5": "1",
                                "Field6": "1",
                                "Field7": "1"
                }] }
```

I am able to create assets araay but I don't know how to add first 2 fields which are `"RequestId": "1234",` and `"OrderID": "NCBTEST02082018-01",` before the assets array.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're exactly doing, but i should be something like this:

```
JsonObject value = Json.createObjectBuilder()
  .add("RequestId", "1234")
  .add("OrderId", "NCB1234")
  .add("Assets", Json.createArrayBuilder()
    .add(Json.createObjectBuilder()
      .add("Field1", "1") // add more in loop
  ).build();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a `org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject`, just do:

```
new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

where `jsonString` is a String containing your entire json object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use new JSONObject(string) to get the required json object
Now coming to order , if you are talking about JSONObject then order is not important as the values are stored under keys which can be accessed randomly unaffected by order
You can create a new JSONObject then add requestid and orderid before adding the assets array

```
JSONObject y=new JSONObject('');
y.put('requestid','whateer');
y.put('orderid','whatever');
y.put('assets',myjsonarray)
```

Comment: This is giving an an exception

Answer (score 0):

Below are just key-value pairs:

**"RequestId": "1234"**

**"OrderID": "NCBTEST02082018-01"**

So, you can insert them in the JSONObject.

Something like this:

```
JSONObject jb = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
        jb.put("Field1", "1");
        jb.put("Field2", "NCBTEST-01");
        jb.put("Field3", "1");
        jb.put("Field4", "1");
        jb.put("Field5", "1");
        jb.put("Field6", "1");
        jb.put("Field7", "1");
        ja.put(jb);


        JSONObject main = new JSONObject();
        main.put("RequestId", "1234");
        main.put("OrderID", "NCBTEST02082018-01");
        main.put("Assets", ja);

        System.out.println(main);
```

Output:

```
{
    "RequestId": "1234",
    "Assets": [{
        "Field4": "1",
        "Field5": "1",
        "Field2": "NCBTEST-01",
        "Field3": "1",
        "Field6": "1",
        "Field7": "1",
        "Field1": "1"
    }],
    "OrderID": "NCBTEST02082018-01"
}
```

Comment: Worked! but why those fields are not coming in order in which we are putting them?

Comment: As per JSON specification, "An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs". Check:                                                                     
                        http://www.json.org/  ,          https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948206/json-order-mixed-up