# Request payload is not formatted properly

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

[image: The Request payload]

Why is my request payload does not send exactly the same format? It should be s_pNumber at the top but instead, it put s_address first and same goes to the others attribute. It changes their place.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON order mixed up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948206/json-order-mixed-up)

Comment: Does the order make any difference?

Comment: i guess yeah, because my database is not updated hmm idk why

Comment: Dev tools show the object properties in alphabet order. Its not order in JSON sended in request.

Comment: okey, i understand right now