# Why does Json object comes before Json values in below?

Tags: java, json

I am trying to create nested json object using `org.json.simple.JSONObject`. why does jsonobject change order?

**Expected output:**

```
{  
  "id":"14",   
  "email":"xxx@gmail.com",    
  "Company":{   
    "address":"milton street",   
    "postal code":"cincinnati",   
    "name":"abc"  
  }  
}
```

**Current Output:**

```
{  
"Company":{   
"address":"milton street",    
"postal code":"cincinnati",    
"name":"abc"  
},   
"id":"14",   
"email":"xxx@gmail.com"  
}
```

**Here is my code:**

```
 JSONObject First = new JSONObject();
    First.put("id", "14");
    First.put("email", "xxx@gmail.com");

    JSONObject companydetails = new JSONObject();
    companydetails.put("name", "abc");
    companydetails.put("address", "milton street");
    companydetails.put("postal code", "cincinnati");

    First.put("Company",companydetails);

    System.out.println(First.toString());
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948206/json-order-mixed-up
JSONObject do not order keys, they are just in random order. Also you don't need that because you get values by keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use google/gson library

```
JsonObject o=new JsonObject();
o.addProperty("id", "14");
o.addProperty("email", "xxx@gmail.com");

JsonObject companydetails1 = new JsonObject();
companydetails1.addProperty("name", "abc");
companydetails1.addProperty("address", "milton street");
companydetails1.addProperty("postal code", "cincinnati");

o.add("Company",companydetails1);
System.out.println(o.toString());
```

with maven repo

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

or with the external jar [download](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/gson/gson-2.2.2.jar.zip)

Comment: Hi Arun, Your solution is working fine. Does this gson accept if i inject json array? in case i have add property with multiple values

Comment: Thanks Arun, I tried jsonarray in gson its working fine. One last question do we have any xml based library which do similar magic like gson in case i have to generate nested xml?

Comment: sorry. i don't know

Answer (score 1):

See the answer here: [JSON order mixed up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948206/json-order-mixed-up)

You cannot and should not rely on the ordering of elements within a JSON object.

From the JSON specification at http://www.json.org/:

"An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs"

As a consequence, JSON libraries are free to rearrange the order of the elements as they see fit. This is not a bug.

Answer (score 0):

JsonObject doesn't maintain the order, and it doesn't matter as you will be accessing the json by keys.

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestJUnit {
    @Test
    public void exec() {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();

        String toPrint = gson.toJson(ToJsonFormat.builder()
                .id(14)
                .email("xxx@gmail.com")
                .company(Company.builder()
                        .address("milton street")
                        .postCode("cincinnati")
                        .name("abc")
                        .build())
                .build());

        System.out.println(toPrint);
    }

    @Getter
    @Builder
    private static class ToJsonFormat {
        private int id;
        private String email;
        private Company company;
    }

    @Getter
    @Builder
    private static class Company {
        private String address;
        @JsonProperty("post code")
        private String postCode;
        private String name;
    }
}
```

result:

```
{"id":14,"email":"xxx@gmail.com","company":{"address":"milton street","post_code":"cincinnati","name":"abc"}}
```

Comment: It would help if you added some narrative explaining how your proposal answers the question.