# Parsing JSON in Spring boot application

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

I'm having trouble in thinking up a way of parsing this type of JSON. I need to be able to access both data and message separately after getting this response inside my application.

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "email": "eskaferas@gmail.com",
            "firstName": "Seras",
            "lastName": "Meras"
        },
        {
            "email": "Soras@gmail.com",
            "firstName": "Oras",
            "lastName": "Moras"
        },
        {
            "email": "bzbzb@gmail.com",
            "firstName": "hello",
            "lastName": "bye"
        },
        {
            "email": "lrc@gmail.com",
            "firstName": "Seras",
            "lastName": "Meras"
        }
    ],
    "message": "Success"
}
```

Could anyone suggest a method specifically for Spring boot? Or a common way that is used in Spring boot to parse this type of JSON.

Thank you.

**EDIT**

My main questions would be just what tool can be used for Spring Boot and what would my POJO class look like if I used Jackson. Would it be something like this?:

```
public class testPojo {
  Users[] users;
  String message;
}
```

Comment: Can you share you code so far?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Have you gone through any documentation or samples provided by Spring official website?

Comment: Write 'How to parse JSON java' in Google please.

Comment: So far I only have my own service that communicates with different responses which I did not need to parse. This is the response I'm getting from another REST service I'm connecting to and just having trouble of thinking up with a way to parse it to an object or objects. I have only checked other questions here, but did not find a way for this type of JSON. I'm just not even sure where to start. Also, if possible I would need not to use any external JAR files. I can use maven dependencies.

Comment: If you are trying to have someone else do this for you, then you should learn to solve your own problems. This can be quickly solved by a simple google search.

Comment: @Abhijith Nagarajan The main question for me is if I use Jackson in this instance how would my POJO class would look like? Would it just be an array of users and a string message?

Comment: @SvajunasKavaliauskas as Mike Tung said, do a google search before posting a question, here is a [guide](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/). If you face problems come back with a question regarding the problem that you have.

Comment: @Dimitris Alright, thank you I will come back if I run into any problems with specific code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pojo class will look like:

```
public class TestPojo{

    private Users[] data;
    private String message;

    public Users[] getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Users[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
     }
}

class Users {
    private String email;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

use @RequestBody in your controller's method parameter.

```
@RestController
class AbcController{

    PostMapping("/api")
    public String create(@RequestBody TestPojo test){
    // you can acess your json in test object
    return "done"
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It is a bit clearer now.

Comment: Let me know if you find any issue while implementing the same.

Comment: Needed getter setters as Jackson in spring boot by default converts the json to the pojo object with the help of getter setter methods.

Comment: Hi again. Just wanted to ask, how would the pojo look like if instead after data there would be { } instead of [] and only one user inside that data. I'm confused since then there is two opening { in a row.I can edit my question to make it clealer if you need.

Comment: { "data": {
            "email": "eskaferas@gmail.com",
            "firstName": "Seras",
            "lastName": "Meras"
        }, "message" : "hello"}      for this kind of json data the pojo will be public  in the TestPojo class instead of Users[] it will be only Users

Comment: change Users[] to Users in the TestPojo and its getter setter

Comment: Alright thank you very much!

Comment: Oh sorry, the json is not like that after all. It starts{ "data"{ { "email"... thats what im struggling with. And I'm upvoting, but the votes are not recorded because od the still low reputation. I will add the json in a minute.

Comment: can you provide the full json properly ?

Comment: { "data":{ { "email": "eskaferas@gmail.com", "firstName": "Seras", "lastName": "Meras" }},"message":"Success"}

Comment: This is not a valid json. data key can't contain {{ it should be [{ (a list of user objects)

Comment: Yes it was the previous option without the extra {}. Sorry to bother you. Thank you for all the help. I will try to move forward.

Answer (score 1):

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MapperFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.PropertyNamingStrategy;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class TestJUnit {

    @Test
    public void exec() {
       String json = "{" +
               "    \"data\": [" +
               "        {" +
               "            \"email\": \"eskaferas@gmail.com\"," +
               "            \"firstName\": \"Seras\"," +
               "            \"lastName\": \"Meras\"" +
               "        }," +
               "        {" +
               "            \"email\": \"Soras@gmail.com\"," +
               "            \"firstName\": \"Oras\"," +
               "            \"lastName\": \"Moras\"" +
               "        }," +
               "        {" +
               "            \"email\": \"bzbzb@gmail.com\"," +
               "            \"firstName\": \"hello\"," +
               "            \"lastName\": \"bye\"" +
               "        }," +
               "        {" +
               "            \"email\": \"lrc@gmail.com\"," +
               "            \"firstName\": \"Seras\"," +
               "            \"lastName\": \"Meras\"" +
               "        }" +
               "    ]," +
               "    \"message\": \"Success\"" +
               "}".replaceAll(" ", "");

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        try {
            JsonParser parser = mapper.readValue(json, JsonParser.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private static class JsonParser {
        private List<Data> data;
        private String message;
    }

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private static class Data{
        private String email;
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
    }

//    @Configuration
    private static class Configuration{
    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper(){
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE);
        mapper.enable(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES);
        mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);
        mapper.setVisibility(mapper.getSerializationConfig()
                .getDefaultVisibilityChecker().withFieldVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
                .withGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
                .withSetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
                .withCreatorVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE));
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_ENUMS_USING_TO_STRING);
        mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.READ_ENUMS_USING_TO_STRING);
        return mapper;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. How could I then serialise it back from my object to Json String? To get the same string as the starting one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55728274/why-does-json-object-comes-before-json-values-in-below/55729156?noredirect=1#comment98137568_55729156