# Spring Convert from PostgreSQL into Geojson FeatureCollection

Tags: json, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, geojson

I've got problem with convert data from postgreSQL into geojson and expose the data to the specified endpoint.

Data in Database (db name: Shops):

shop_id => BIGINT
shop_name => VARCHAR
Shop_position => geography => after using ST_AsGeoJson we receive longitude and latitude
Shop_radius => DOUBLE

Repository:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


@Repository
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class GeoRepository {

    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
   
    String GET_SHOPS = "select 'FeatureCollection' As type, array_to_json(array_agg(f)) As features from (select 'Feature' As type,ST_AsGeoJSON(lg.\"Shop_position\") :: json as geometry,row_to_json((select t from (select \"Shop_id\",\"Shop_name\",\"Shop_radius\") As t )) As properties from public.\"Shops\" As lg) as f;";
   
    public List<Map<String,Object>> getDataFromDb(String query){

        List<Map<String,Object>> data = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(query);
        return data;
    }
    
    public List<Map<String,Object>> getShops() throws JsonProcessingException { return getDataFromDb(GET_SHOPS); }
}
```

Service:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.json.JSONObject;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.boot.admin_panel.exception.DataNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.boot.admin_panel.repository.GeoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class GeoService {

    private final GeoRepository geoRepository;
    private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public String getGeoJsonShops(){
        try{
            if(geoRepository.getShops() == null){
                throw new DataNotFoundException("Shops data is not found");
            }else
            return mapper.writeValueAsString(geoRepository.getShops());
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
            throw new NullPointerException("NullPointException");
        }
    }
    
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.json.JSONObject;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.json.JSONParser;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.json.ParseException;
import org.springframework.boot.admin_panel.service.GeoService;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/admin_panel")
@CrossOrigin
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DataController {

    private final DataService dataService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/get_shops", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity getShops() {
        String outputData = geoService.getGeoJsonShops();
        if(outputData == null){
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }else {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(outputData);
        }
    }
}
```

This controller return:

```
[
    {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": {
            "type": "json",
            "value": "[{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[34.642697,74.341718]},\"properties\":{\"Shop_id\":125,\"Shop_name\":\"Grocery_Lux_Shop\",Shop_radius\":0.34637}}]"
        }
    }
]
```

But there's one problem inside "value" property it's not json but a string.
What has been wrongly made that I dont receive json? I guess it's a badly SQL syntax.

Could anyone help me ?
I want to receive format similarly like this:

```
{"type" : "FeatureCollection", "features" : [{"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type":"Point","coordinates":[1,1]}, "properties": {"id": 1, "name": "one"}}, {"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type":"Point","coordinates":[2,2]}, "properties": {"id": 2, "name": "two"}}, {"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type":"Point","coordinates":[3,3]}, "properties": {"id": 3, "name": "three"}}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I guess it's a badly SQL syntax.

No, it is not a bad syntax. What is being returned is equivalent to javascripts `JSON.stringify`.

You need to map the 'value' to a POJO using Jackson object mapper. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55748151/1156233) answer for a way to do it.

Comment: Ok I understand, but I could reach this target without creating class Shop with attributes? I don't want to create other classes and focus only on repository,service and controller.

Comment: try assigning it to a variable of type 'Object' and then read the value to that variable using ObjectMapper. I am not sure, how nested fields will be treated.

Comment: Object not supports nested fields, could You show me how to do this with POJO ? Maybe I must forEach my List<Map<String,Object>> into Map<String,Object> and then assigning to variables?