# Elasticsearch stored_fields order

Tags: elasticsearch

I've run into an order peculiarity with the stored_fields of Elasticsearch. Basically, the stored_fields are not retrieved in the order I specify in the request. As an example, I create the following index with three fields and request the fields in a specific order:

```
PUT /test_field_order
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "field1": { "type": "text", "store": true},
      "field2": { "type": "text", "store": true},
      "field3": { "type": "text", "store": true}
    }
  }
}

PUT /test_field_order/_doc/1
{
  "field1": "field1",
  "field2": "field2",
  "field3": "field3"
}

GET test_field_order/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "_id": 1
    }
  },
  "stored_fields": ["field3", "field1", "field2"]
}
```

After running this on Kibana, the following is retrieved:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test_field_order",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "fields" : {
          "field1" : [
            "field1"
          ],
          "field3" : [
            "field3"
          ],
          "field2" : [
            "field2"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

As you can see, the stored_fields are retrieved in the order [field1, field3, field2]. This doesn't match with the order of the request [field3, field1, field2]. Furthermore, it doesn't match with the index order [field1, field2, field3] either. How is the retrieve order determined? Does Elasticsearch guarantee that the order of stored_fields match the order of fields in the request? I couldn't find any specification about the ordering.

Answer (score 0):

You can not order Json field.Here a good explanation and specification [JSON order mixed up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948206/json-order-mixed-up/4920304#4920304)