# Why is my dictionary unordered even thought I'm using python version 3.10?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create an endpoint that returns data in specific order when called.

Here is an example version that is working correctly:

```
example = {
  "responseVersion": "v3",
  "totalCount": 0,
  "sections": [
    {
      "id": "123",
      "title": "Invoice ID: 1234",
      "linkUrl": "http://example.com/1",
      "tokens": [
        {
          "label": "Valid",
          "dataType": "STRING",
          "value": "2019-08-04 - 2020-08-04",
          "name": "valid_date",
        },
        {
          "label": "STATUS",
          "dataType": "STATUS",
          "name": "status",
          "value": "Ended",
        }
      ],
    },
  ]
}

 @app.get("/")
 async def root():
  return example
```

Here is a simplified version of the code that I'm trying to get working:

```
def create_contract_cards(data):
  cards = []
  for i in data:
    card = {
      "id": i["ContractID"],
      "title": "Invoice ID: {}".format(i["ContractID"]),
      "linkUrl": "http://example.com/1",
      "tokens": [
        {
          "label": "Valid",
          "dataType": "STRING",
          "value": "2019-08-04 - 2020-08-04",
          "name": "valid_date",
        },
        {
          "label": "STATUS",
          "dataType": "STATUS",
          "name": "status",
          "value": "Ended",
        }
      ]
    }
    cards.append(card)

  example_data = {
  "responseVersion": "v3",
  "totalCount": len(cards),
  "sections": cards
  }
  return example_data

 @app.get("/")
 async def root():
  #data will be fetched here from another endpoint but i leave it out to keep things simple
  all_cards = create_contract_cards(data)
  pprint(all_cards) 
  return all_cards
```

At this point I'd expect everything working correctly, but the the data is actually is getting reordered which I thought shouldn't happen if using Python 3.7 or above.

> As of Python version 3.7, dictionaries are ordered. In Python 3.6 and
> earlier, dictionaries are unordered.

Here is pretty printed output of that all_cards variable:

```
{'responseVersion': 'v3',
 'sections': [{'id': 'C000000010',
               'linkUrl': 'http://example.com/1',
               'title': 'Invoice ID: C000000010',
               'tokens': [{'dataType': 'STRING',
                           'label': 'Valid',
                           'name': 'valid_date',
                           'value': '2019-08-04 - 2020-08-04'},
                          {'dataType': 'STATUS',
                           'label': 'STATUS',
                           'name': 'status',
                           'value': 'Ended'}]}],
 'totalCount': 1}
```

As you can see its not in the same order when I created it.

I've also tried to use OrderedDict():

```
def create_contract_cards(data):
  cards = []
  for i in data:
    card = OrderedDict()
    card['id'] = i["ContractID"]
    card['title'] = i["ContractID"]
    card['linkUrl'] = "http://example.com/1"
    card['tokens'] = [
        {
          "label": "Valid",
          "dataType": "STRING",
          "value": "2019-08-04 - 2020-08-04",
          "name": "valid_date",
        },
        {
          "label": "STATUS",
          "dataType": "STATUS",
          "name": "status",
          "value": "Ended",
        }
      ]
    cards.append(card)

  example_data = {
  "responseVersion": "v3",
  "totalCount": len(cards),
  "sections": cards
  }
  return example_data

 @app.get("/")
 async def root():
  #data will be fetched here from another endpoint but i leave it out to keep things simple
  all_cards = create_contract_cards(data) 
  return all_cards
```

Does anyone has a idea why is this happening and why my code doesn't work like the first example?

All help is appreciated, thanks in advace!

The technologies used in the project:

- Python version 3.10.5 (poetry)
- FastAPI

Comment: `"As you can see its not in the same order when I created it."` Actually we can't see. the source of `data` is excluded and you are telling us to assume it is in a particular ordering.

Comment: If I had to guess, the issue is likely with the jsonification, json is not ordered.  This is discussed more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948206/json-order-mixed-up

Comment: What exactly are you trying to order? In your first example your `totalCount` is 0 and `sections` is a list with a single entry. In the final example `totalCount` is 1 and `sections` is a list with a single entry. Lists retain ordering. What dictionary are you trying to order, the fields of the single `card` dictionary?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html _"Dictionaries are sorted by key before the display is computed."_

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is not with the dictionary but with `pprint`. It sorts keys alphabetically by default. Use `sort_dicts=False` to avoid this:

```
pprint(all_cards, sort_dicts=False)
```

But in general, you should not rely on keys being ordered.